# How to save ping result to text file from database?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my web form I have a `GridView` that displays the device name as well as the IP address.  It then pings that IP address and displays either a success or time out by showing various icons.

I would like to save that result to a text file in this format:

```
Server 1  1.1.1.1 Round Trip Time 23 ms
```

At the moment with the below code I get the following:

```
1.1.1.1 Round Trip Time 23 ms
```

It is not displaying the device name?

Here is my code I am using at the moment:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                Image Image3 = (Image)row.FindControl("Image3");
                Image Image4 = (Image)row.FindControl("Image4");
                Image Image5 = (Image)row.FindControl("Image5");
                string destIP = GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
                {
                    try
                    {
                        System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping p = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping();
                        System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply reply;
                        reply = p.Send(destIP);

                        if (reply.Status == System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPStatus.Success)
                        {
                            Image3.Visible = true;
                            Image3.ToolTip = Convert.ToString("Round Trip Time: " + reply.RoundtripTime + "ms");
                            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"c:\Temp\ping results.txt", true)) //// true to append data to the file
                            {
                              writer.WriteLine(destIP + "  " + Convert.ToString("Round Trip Time: " + reply.RoundtripTime + " ms"));
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Image4.Visible = true;
                            Image4.ToolTip = reply.Status.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingException err)
                    {
                        Image4.Visible = true;
                        Image4.ToolTip = err.Message.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Where is the server Id located, in your grid ? Also you can remove `Convert.ToString(` entirely

Comment: `writer.WriteLine(destIP + "  " + Convert.ToString("Round Trip Time: " + reply.RoundtripTime + " ms"));` - you are not _writing_ the deviceName ....

Comment: I know that, thats why I need to know how to write the device name as well

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I got it working.  What I did was to these few lines:

```
string CellValue = GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex]["Device"].ToString();
writer.WriteLine(CellValue + "," + destIP + "," + "Round Trip Time: " + reply.RoundtripTime + " ms");
```

Thanks For All the help